# How to enter values in the custom list view of edit text, I lose the value of the first edit text when i select 2nd edit text

Tags: android, listview, android-custom-view

I used a custom list view with four Edit text and I set the limit of the list. after that when I put the values in the edit text, I select one edit text and enter the value after that I select the second edit text then first loss his value, I cannot enter the values in the list:

```
  listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listPrice);
     final int value = size;
            for (int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
                arrayList.add(i);
            }
      Button buttonAdd = new Button(this);
            buttonAdd.setText("ADD");
            listView.addFooterView(buttonAdd);
            customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(ProductSizePrice.this, 
R.layout.product_suze_detail, arrayList);
            listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

Custom Adapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {


    private List<Integer> list;
    private List<ShowProducts> listShowProducts;
    private Context context;
    private int resource;
    private String condition;
    String uri;
    int i = 0;

    public CustomAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull List<Integer> objects, String condition) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.list = objects;
        this.condition = condition;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return super.getCount();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return super.getItem(position);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        //    SurgicalonDetail surgicalonDetail=list.get(position);

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(resource, parent, false);
        if (condition == "Size_Price") {
            EditText size = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etSize);
            EditText quantity = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etQuantity);
            EditText price = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etPrice);
            EditText cost = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etCost);
            ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.productSizePriceLayout);
        return view;

    }
}
```

Getting the values from edit text

```
for (int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
                    View view = listView.getChildAt(i);
EditText etSize = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etSize);
                    EditText etQuantity = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etQuantity);
                    EditText etPrice = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etPrice);
                    EditText etCost = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etCost);
String sizeShow = etSize.getText().toString();
                    String quantityShow = etQuantity.getText().toString();
                    String priceShow = etPrice.getText().toString();
                    String costShow = etCost.getText().toString();

 arrayListSize.add(sizeShow.toString());
                        arrayListQuantity.add(Integer.parseInt(quantityShow.toString()));
                        arrayListPrice.add(Integer.parseInt(priceShow.toString()));
                        arrayListCost.add(Integer.parseInt(costShow.toString()));
```

Comment: How do you persist the values of each EditText, if you do?

Comment: 4 Edit text names{size-name, price, quantity, cost},

Comment: these edit Text shown in list view list length is 5,  6, or some thing when i enter the record i select the first edit text and enter the data after that i select the 2nd edit text then first edit text clear the text i can not enter the text in edit text , some time 2 or 3 edit text hold value but at least they also clear the text

Comment: i am new developer i can not understand whats happen

Comment: If you don't persist the values of each EditText, how do you pretend to reload them when they are recreated?

Comment: check this video   https://youtu.be/KdK3ElXtJz8